# How to find (x,y) coordinate from an angle

Tags: javascript, geometry, angle, coordinate, degrees

i need help. I want to find the coordinate from the green point in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9Oi2.jpg), as you know that the red points is the first position and it rotate for 75,17 degree.

The length of the both line is same. Please help me to resolve this math. I need that for my script code.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. This is maths, not programming, and thus kind of off topic. But this is what trigonometry is made to do. Check `Math.sin` and `Math.cos`.

Comment: yes i know that, but i confuse. i just want to create new coordinate of an object in x and y axis when i am input the angle.

Answer (score 0):

```
function blah(oX, oY, angle) {
  var radius = Math.sqrt(oX * oX + oY * oY);
  var oTheta = Math.atan2(oX, oY);
  var nTheta = oTheta - angle * Math.PI / 180;
  return {x: radius * Math.sin(nTheta), y: radius * Math.cos(nTheta)};
}

var newPoint = blah(0, -83, 75.17); // use positive for counterclockwise angle, negative for clockwise angle
console.log(newPoint.x, newPoint.y);
```